# How to check if a treeview is empty

Tags: vb.net, treeview

This seems simple but I am having a mental block at the moment.
Please can anyone just tell me how to check if a Treeview control is completely empty when the user clicks a button?

I am using Visual Basic 2010 express.

Comment: Are you asking if there are no nodes, or if there are nodes but none of them have data?

Comment: `If treeView1.Nodes.Count = 0 Then`

Comment: @TonyHinkle - Thanks for your time. LarsTech has given me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Button1_Click('*all handles....*)
       If Me.trvResources.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
         'Your Stuff here
       End If
End Sub
```

trvResources is my Treeview name